# How to replace a string defined by starting and ending index by another string in R?

Tags: r, string, substr

```
string <- "this is a funny cat"
```

I want to replace the first 15 characters of `string` with 'orange`. The desired output is

```
'orange cat'
```

However, using `substr` gives me

```
substr(string, 1, 15) <- "orange"
> string
[1] "oranges a funny cat"
```

which is not the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `substr` should be the `pattern` of `sub`.

```r
string <- "this is a funny cat"

sub(substr(string, 1, 15), "orange", string)
[1] "orange cat"
```

Or directly replace the first 15 characters in `sub`.

```r
sub("^.{15}", "orange", string)
[1] "orange cat"
```

Comment: Thanks, for the second solution you posted, what if I want to replace character index from 3 to 15 instead of 1 to 15? Is there a way to do this? The desired output would be 'thorange cat` (for replacing the 3rd to 15th character with 'orange')

Comment: In that case you might do `sub("(^.{2}).{13}", "\\1orange", string)`, but then I think `substr` would be much clearer in this case.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I have a follow up question (related to using `sub` and `substr`) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76394451/why-is-sub-in-r-not-recognizing-the-pattern-that-i-provided-in-r For some reason, `sub` is not recognizing the pattern based on `substr()`. If you have a chance, would appreciate you taking a look