# Why is sub in R not recognizing the pattern that I provided in R?

Tags: r, string, substr

```
mystring <- c("code IS (384333)\n   AND parse = TURE \n ) \n 
              \n code IS (43343344)\n ) some information here
              code IS (23423422) ) and more information")
```

I'm trying to replace the 2nd to 40th characters of `mystring` with `"HELLO"`. However, `sub` is not giving me the correct output:

```
> sub(pattern = substr(mystring, 2, 40), replacement = "HELLO", mystring)
[1] "code IS (384333)\n   AND parse = TURE \n ) \n \n              \n code IS (43343344)\n ) some information here\n              code IS (23423422) ) and more information"
```

The correct output is

```
[1] "cHELLO \n \n              \n code IS (43343344)\n ) some information here\n              code IS (23423422) ) and more information"
```

Comment: You need to use `fixed = TRUE`. i.e. `sub(pattern = substr(mystring, 2, 40), replacement = "HELLO", mystring, fixed = T)`